# multi-page text drawing to a pdf with monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, pdf, xamarin.ios, core-graphics

I'm writing a text file of indeterminate length to a PDF page. If the file has more text than will fit on the page, I need to add a second PDF page. However, I can't seem to get the drawing/graphics context to start drawing on the next page. It generates a new page just fine, but it stays blank.

Here's my code:

```
public static FileInfo writeTextToPDF(FileInfo input) {
    if(!input.Exists)
        return default(FileInfo); //Return null if there is no log to be written

    UIGraphics.BeginPDFContext (input.FullName + ".pdf", RectangleF.Empty, default(NSDictionary));

    UIGraphics.BeginPDFPage ();

    using (CGContext g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext()) {
        const int marginTop = 12; //Margin to leave at the top of the page
        const int marginLeft = 12; //Margin to leave at the left of the page
        const int lineSpacing = 4; //Space between lines
        const int fontSize = 8; //Change this to change the font size

        var yOffset = -marginTop - fontSize; //This is easier for drawing than translating a CTM all the time

        g.ScaleCTM (1, -1);

        //Write the title
        g.SelectFont ("Helvetica", fontSize * 2, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
        g.ShowTextAtPoint (marginLeft, yOffset, input.Name);
        yOffset -= fontSize * 2 + lineSpacing * 2;

        g.SelectFont ("Helvetica", fontSize, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
        using (var fs = input.OpenText()) {
            string text = fs.ReadLine ();
            while(text != null) {
                    g.ShowTextAtPoint (marginLeft, yOffset, text); //Draw it 12 points from the left
                yOffset -= fontSize + lineSpacing; //Move down another line
                text = fs.ReadLine (); //Get the next line

                if(-yOffset >= UIGraphics.PDFContextBounds.Height) {
                    // Start a new page if needed
                    //g.EndPage ();
                    UIGraphics.BeginPDFPage ();

                    yOffset = -marginTop - fontSize;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    UIGraphics.EndPDFContent ();

    return new FileInfo (input.FullName + ".pdf");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two lines:

```
if(-yOffset >= UIGraphics.PDFContextBounds.Height) {
    // Start a new page if needed
    //g.EndPage ();
    UIGraphics.BeginPDFPage ();

    **g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
    g.ScaleCTM (1, -1);**

    yOffset = -marginTop - fontSize;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I figured out too. I had to take g out of a using block, and dispose of it, but this is essentially it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mapo80/iTextSharp-Monotouch

Not using ITextSharp for Xamarin.IOS?

I'm teasing, but it is a possible answer. : )